# Java - Comparing a single String value with all the String values in an ArrayList

Tags: java, string, list, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList` with a set of (same) string values which I need to compare  with a single String value and return true or false. Is there any way to do 
that in Java?

For example, say I have a `<String>ArrayList` with 5 values = foo, foo, foo, foo, foo (My requirement is such that all the values in the arraylist will be the SAME) and I have a `String str = "foo"`. I need to verify that whether ALL the values in the arraylist is the SAME as the string value i.e., all the values present in the arraylist SHOULD be `"foo"`.

I tried to google this info and all I can see is suggestions to use `contains()` method, in different ways, which will return true even if anyone value in the arraylist contains the specified value.

I even figured a workaround for this - Creating another arraylist with expected values and compare the two lists using `equals()` method and it seems 
to be working. I was just wondering whether there is any simple way to achieve this.

Comment: Just iterate the list and compare each item with your `String`. If all are equal, `true`, if any is not, `false`.

Comment: I can do that but I was looking for a single line solution, exactly like what @steffen has suggested.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's simple with Java 8:

```
String str = "foo";
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "foo");
boolean allMatch = strings.stream().allMatch(s -> s.equals(str));
```

For Java 7 replace the last line with:

```
boolean allMatch = true;
for (String string : strings) {
    if (!string.equals(str)) {
        allMatch = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: For clarity maybe `final String str = "foo";`. And for thousand foos, a `parallelStream()` might be an idea.

Comment: Java 8 is rolling in. +1

Comment: @steffen Excellent! This is exactly what I'm looking for and it worked. Thank You!! 
Also, I'm new to java. So, It will be more helpful if you can explain what exactly this line does `boolean allMatch = strings.stream().allMatch(s -> s.equals(str));`

Comment: @justcurious There's tons of documentation about it out there and it's too complex to explain here. Search for Java 8 Lambdas and Streams. In short: Java 8 offers streams which are similar to Unix pipes. With streams you iterate collections and perform one or more operations. `allMatch()` is a short-circuiting terminal operation meaning that the iteration stops immediately after the first non-matching item is encountered and returns `false`. If all items match, it returns `true`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This helps :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to know if the array contains the string use [ArrayList::contains()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains(java.lang.Object))

```
String s = "HI";
ArrayList<String> strings = // here you have your string

if (string.contains(s)) {
    // do your stuff
}
```

If you want to check if **all values** are same, iterate and count. If you have JAVA8 check [steffen sollution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32201993/3850595).

```
boolean areSame = true;
for (String str : strings) {
    if (!str.equals(s)) areSame = false;
}

if (areSame) {
    // all elements are same
}
```

Comment: OP said this was not what they wanted, as it only sees if one string is equal

Comment: The problem is that he wants to check if **every** entry in the list is the same value.

Comment: OP said all strings in the list must be compared to be equal to the given string.

Answer (score 3):

1) You can the pass the arraylist into a set.

2) Now you can get the size of set, if it is equal to 1 that means all elements are same.

3) Now you can use the contains on set to check if your value is present in it or not.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
          String toBeCompared="foo";
          List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
          list.add("foo");
          list.add("foo");
          list.add("foo");
          list.add("foo");
          list.add("foo");
          Set<String> set=new HashSet<String>(list);
          if(1==set.size()){
              System.out.println(set.contains(toBeCompared));
          }
          else{
             System.out.println("List has different values");
          }
    }
```

Comment: Or use `Set.contains()` for step 3.

Comment: Something like this? `new HashSet(list).size() == 1 && str.equals(list.get(0))` - Not getting it from the set to make it single line.

Comment: @KDM - `HashSet<String>` or `HashSet<>` would be better, I believe.

Comment: @RealSkeptic not in java 8 when passing a collection. Point noted.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Thanks for your comment, edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this method to do that

```
private boolean allAreSame(ArrayList<String> stringList, String compareTo){
    for(String s:stringList){
        if(!s.equals(compareTo))
             return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: should use !equals instead of !=

Comment: it will return the same thing, but i will fix it

Comment: FYI: `==` tests for reference equality (whether they are the same object).
`.equals()` tests for value equality (whether they are logically "equal").
Consequently, if you want to test whether two strings have the same value you should use `.equals()`, because there're plenty of cases when `==` *wouldn't* return `true` for comparison.

Comment: thank you for future reference, but i have already fixed it :)

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
ArrayList<String> foos = new ArrayList<>();
String str = "foo";     
for (String string : foos) {
    if(string.equals(str)){
            System.out.println("True");
    }
}
```